# Mass upload of images?

Tags: ee3, file-manager

I am new to EE and I am only using a free version of EE 3.3. Nevertheless, I have noticed that you can only upload one image at a time for the file manager. Is any other way to create a drag and drop with EE's file manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of people use [Assets](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets), I believe [Channel Images](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-images-ee2) would also work for you.  If you're using EE3 [this](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-images) is the Channel Images link.  I don't believe Assets is finished for EE3 just yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. The official way is to FTP files directly into your upload directory on the server, the synchronize. In your Upload Directory settings, you should see that synchronize link somewhere.

This method, however, can be unnecessarily timely if you have thousands of files in a directory, and you only want to add, say, 10.

2. My custom hack has been to create a channel, Mass Uploads, and make one field in it of the "File Grid" type (EE5). Drag and drop to mass upload, then simply close the entry. Check File Manager and you'll see that your files are there.